# How would you go about designing a CNN that searches for one specific face in thousands of images?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, face-detection, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a CNN that I can train on several images of one specific face found in old paintings with the objective of feeding the model with thousands of other images it has never seen before and returning images with similar features, preferably returning a probability value in terms of similarity with the trained data.

I've been running into a couple of problems so I'm wondering what your approach would be.

Answer (score 0):

when you just train (for example) your face against a bunch of random faces, so your face has the label 1 and random faces have label 0, then it should differenciate between your face and other faces. But to check in a bunch of faces which are the same you would have to use the [siamese neural network method](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-shot-learning-with-siamese-networks-using-keras-17f34e75bb3d). This will give you, when trained correctly, a similarity score between two faces. This should be what you were searching for (I hope :) !

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll look into the Siamese neural network. I'm currently working with two classes, one with the face I'm looking for and another with random faces. Training accuracy is great but testing falls down to 70% at best. Perhaps I should use face detection on the input data so the network only trains on the actual faces and not the other parts of the image.